# When did tagging become user responsibiliy?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki, stack-exchange-history

I was looking back at an ealier beta version of stackoverflow and noticed that tags were previously a fix in the site. When did they become user responsibility?

Comment: Tags have always been the user responsibility. Where did you get the impression that was ever different?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters See link: https://web.archive.org/web/20080925202811/http://stackoverflow.com/tags And i quote "Stack Overflow questions are grouped by tags, created by programmers just like you. Using the right tags makes it easier for other programmers to find and answer your question.

Here's a list of all current tags, along with a count of how many questions each tag contains." And i misinterpreting this sentence?

Comment: You are; the tags are created by users of the site, as needed, so when you create a question, if you have [enough reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) you can create a tag if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters yes I know that NOW they are. But was it the case earlier? And on what grounds are you basing your answer? Were you active in 2008?

Comment: Those early days must have been filled with a lot of humor: *Using this website may cause irreversible damage to the kidneys and liver.*

Comment: @Martijn Pieters yes NOW they are. But was it the case in the BETA version in 2008...

Comment: @noawithouth: the target user group of Stack Overflow was 'programmers just like you'. There is nothing in that sentence suggesting that tags could only be created by people with access to the site code.

Comment: @noawithouth: You can listen to the podcasts from those early pre-beta, private beta and public beta days; I was not active then, but principles like how tags work have not changed.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Yes, but this is interpretation now. Do you know it was the case for sure?

Comment: Tagging hasn't changed. For sure. Your archive link includes the [FAQ page](https://web.archive.org/web/20080926064625/http://stackoverflow.com/faq) which includes information on retagging, for example.

Comment: More information is found in the [meta faq](https://web.archive.org/web/20080926064631/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-unofficial-faq) (which was just another post on Stack Overflow then).

Comment: @Martijn Pieters see my self provided answer. I found the proof in the pudding. :)

Comment: I was a beta participant.  There were tags.  I wouldn't be surprised that tags were added later in the development cycle than things such as questions and answers, however this isn't really relevant to anything.

Answer (score 8):

I think you are likely misinterpreting this:

> Stack Overflow questions are grouped by tags, created by programmers just like you. Using the right tags makes it easier for other programmers to find and answer your question. Here's a list of all current tags, along with a count of how many questions each tag contains.

"created by programmers just like you" actually, sort of, means *you* can create them. Although, there may have been limitations in effect there limiting it only to certain reputation users, as it is now.

"Here's a list of all current tags" simply means that those are the tags currently created.

Essentially; that text does not suggest it was ever not the users' responsibility to create tags. In fact, it suggests it's always been.

Answer (score 0):

Tags were always a user controlled function.

See link 
https://web.archive.org/web/20080927153624/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

As you can see, the description on the tag box says :

"Combine multiple words into single-words, space to separate up to 5 tags (python c# ruby)"

Which suggests the ability to freely create a new tag.